# How to send post variables in HttpRedirect or HttpFound in webob in python ?

Tags: python, routes, webob

I want to send some variable in post when i am doing redirecting in my application.

Scenario is like this

```
def redirect_with_post():
  post_variable = "i am a post variable"
  return HttpRedirect(location="/confirm?id=23&user=user1")
```

# Now i want to send
   post_variable

- I want to send variable in post instead of querystring as a post request while redirecting.

tools and software used:-

- python, webob, route

Answer (score 1):

Redirect is performed by the client (your browser). And it only support a single Location header. You can't send POST data through a redirect. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302